# hash password using node crypto scryptSync

Tags: node.js, encryption, salt

I need to secure the user input password of an electron app to create a key for crypto AES ancryption. As suggested here on SO I've replaced the `createHash` function with `scryptSync` function. I'm not sure about the salt.

```
// this is the old method I've used to hash the password to obtain the correct lenght for aes-256-gcm
  // let key = crypto.createHash('sha256')
  //       .update(data.password)
  //       .digest();
// salt creation 
  let salt = crypto.randomBytes(64);
  let key = crypto.scryptSync(data.password, salt, 32);
```

Is there a predefined size that I need to pass to `randomBytes` function for `aes-256-gcm` encryption algo?

Also when I attach the salt to the encrypted output I'm using this code

```
   let encryptedData = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(base64, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);
    let payload = `${salt.toString('base64')}:${iv.toString('base64')}:${encryptedData.toString('base64')}`;
```

Since I'm using the `join()` function to merge multiple encoded strings, I need a way to split them when the encrypted output file needs to be decoded. At the moment I'm using this way, but I've figured out that I need to extract the salt to check the password. Is there a way to do it better?

```
const decryptData = (data) => {
  let output = [];
  // I need the salt here but the file needs to be splitted before
  let key = crypto.scryptSync(data.password, 'salt', 32);

  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(data.path, 'utf8', (err, content) => {
      if(err) return reject(err);
      let fileContents = content.split(' ');
      output = fileContents.map( (file) => {
        let [salt, iv, content] = file.split(':');
        let cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, Buffer.from(iv, 'base64'));
        let decrypted = cipher.update(content, 'base64', 'utf8');
        return decryptedData;
      });
      resolve(output);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Node.js indicates, the hash needs to be minimally 128 bits or 16 bytes. 64 bytes is really too much, I'd max out on 256 bits but 128 is really enough when it comes to a password. As you seem to be aiming at max security, try 32 bytes. Don't forget that requiring a strong password is at least as important, if not more important.

Currently you are using the default cost parameter for `scryptSync`. That's probably not a good idea as it is set to 16384 by default. The higher the better, so try and see what's best for your particular target platforms.

Note that you both know the salt and IV size in bytes. This means that it would be just as easy to get them from a binary string before it is encoded to base 64. That also has some advantages: if you load the binary data into a `Buffer` then you can simply use methods like [`from`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_arraybuffer_byteoffset_length) to get a different view, which can then represent an IV or salt without copying the data.

That's most important for the plaintext of course. You want to copy that as few times as possible.

Comment: The password is inserted by the user so I can only hash it. At the moment I've opted for hex encoding because I'm encrypting data URIs and I've faced some problems during decryption, also I want to avoid double base64 encoding for the data to recrypt

Comment: The hex encoding should really not be necessary. It's probably better to find the root of the problem you are experiencing instead. Above solution only encodes to base 64 once if applied correctly.

Comment: what do you mean with encodes only once? I'm using the encrytion function to encrypt one or more files every time, this is why I choose to use hex for the final output. I've not posted the encryption code but after each file is encrypted, I'm pushing it into an array and then using `join()` I'm writing the final output to a file

Comment: Uh, I think I don't fully grasp your situation yet.. That's often a problem with these kind of questions, they miss enough context. Not that it matters much, my answer should be correct (at least for one iteration of AES-GCM).

Comment: Yes, it's a perfect solution for a single iteration, in fact I've replaced the ranom bytes size from 64 to 32 as you've suggested. I'm generating the salt only once because all files are encrypted with the same key, only the IV will be different. What I was trying to explain is that I'm passing array of files for encryption so I can't really have just a single base64 as final output of the operation but I have more than once if there are multiple files, this is why I've opted for hex :)

Comment: I think I still don't understand why you are talking about hex. Hex has no advantages here. Either you use binary directly (possibly using a (T)LV encoding to distinguish separate files)  or you use multiple base 64 if you require text. Note that hex and binary are not identical. Hex can be used to represent binary in text, but it is rather inefficient compared to base 64.

Comment: Thank you for the tech details. I will do some tests with base64. If you can explain what you mean for `(T)LV encoding` it will be appreciated

Comment: TLV means "tag length value", so you have some kind of type parameter in the tag (in this case optional, because you know the value because of context), then a length field of say 32 bits / 4 bytes and then the value that you are encoding. It's a binary way of separating values (with dynamic sizes).

Comment: An example will be better, I'm new to the concept.

Comment: Here is an example using a single byte for tag (`0c`) and length (`0a` for 10 bytes): `0c0a616e206578616d706c65`. It uses a well known TLV encoding: ASN.1 with DER encoding.